# cl-ppcre:regex-replace and backslashes in replacement

Tags: regex, lisp, common-lisp, cl-ppcre

May be this questions is really stuped, but I'm stuck. How can I put backslashes in `cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all` replacement?

For example I just want to escape some characters like ' " ( ) etc, so I'm going to do with | replacement first, to see that matching is ok:

```
    CL-USER> (princ (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "(['\\(\\)\"])"
"foo \"bar\" 'baz' (test)" "|\\1"))
    PRINTED: foo |"bar|" |'baz|' |(test|)
```

Ok, let's put slash:

```
    CL-USER> (princ (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "(['\\(\\)\"])"
"foo \"bar\" 'baz' (test)" "\\\1"))
    PRINTED: foo "bar" 'baz' (test) ;; No luck
```

No, we nedd two slashes:

```
    CL-USER> (princ (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "(['\\(\\)\"])"
"foo \"bar\" 'baz' (test)" "\\\\1"))
    PRINTED: foo \1bar\1 \1baz\1 \1test\1 ;; Got slash, but not \1
```

Maybe like this?

```
(princ (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "(['\\(\\)\"])"
"foo \"bar\" 'baz' (test)" "\\\{1}"))
PRINTED: foo "bar" 'baz' (test) ;; Nope, no luck here
```

Of course, if I'll put space between slashes everithing is ok, but I don't need it

```
(princ (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "(['\\(\\)\"])"
"foo \"bar\" 'baz' (test)" "\\ \\1"))
PRINTED: foo \ "bar\ " \ 'baz\ ' \ (test\ )
```

So, how can i write to get `foo \"bar\" \'baz\' \(test\)` printed? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Six Source Slashes

```
CL-USER> (princ (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "(['\\(\\)\"])"
                                            "foo \"bar\" 'baz' (test)"
                                            "\\\\\\1"))
foo \"bar\" \'baz\' \(test\)
```

When you write the string in the source code, each slash is being used as an escape.  You want the replacement text to be the sequence of characters `\\1`.  To encode the first slash in the replacement (since CL-PPCRE is going to process slashes), CL-PPCRE needs to see the sequence of characters `\\\1`.  The first two slashes encode the slash, and the third encodes the group number.  To get that sequence of characters as a Lisp string, you have to write `"\\\\\\1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but for others, note that you would do well to avoid strings in such cases:

```
(cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all '(:register (:char-class #\' #\( #\) #\"))
                            "foo \"bar\" 'baz' (test)"
                            '("\\" 0))
```